# PaperClip 3.4: How to regenerate images is _original has been deleted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Does anyone know if it is possible to tell paperclip to use a file other than _original to regenerate thumbnails from?

Our _original files are no longer available and we want to regenerate our thumbnails due to a style size change.

I'm not sure where to even start looking on this one.

Comment: Do you have the originals in another location? Or, do you want to take the largest style available and reprocess them?

Comment: I want to take the largest style available and use that instead of the original to reprocess images, the _originals are gone forever unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I didn't test this out extensively but something like this should work. This is assuming that you're model is defined as:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :attachment, styles: { small: "300x300>", large: "100x100>" }
end
```

This is a script that will use `open-uri` to treat URLs as File streams so you can pull the `large` style by URL, update the model and then reprocess each image.

```
require 'open-uri'

Image.find_each do |image|
  large_image = open(image.attachment.url(:large)) {|f| f.read }

  image = large_image
  image.reprocess!
end
```

Again, I only did some basic testing with this and I'm not 100% that the `image =` assignment will need more than just the file stream, but I did test it with one image and it seemed to work. It retained all of the existing image data and used the `large` style when reprocessing all of the existing image and added it as an original.

Hope that helps. Good luck.